# can anyone explain how does $flipCount work?

Tags: php

I have some trouble understanding the following recursive code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
           <title>More Coin Flips</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <p>We will keep flipping a coin as long as the result is heads!</p>
       <?php
       $flipCount = 0;
       do {
           $flip = rand(0,1);
           $flipCount ++;
           if ($flip){
               echo "<div class=\"coin\">H</div>";
           }
           else {
               echo "<div class=\"coin\">T</div>";
           }
       } while ($flip);
       $verb = "were";
       $last = "flips";
       if ($flipCount == 1) {
           $verb = "was";
           $last = "flip";
       }
       echo "<p>There {$verb} {$flipCount} {$last}!</p>";
       ?>
       </body>enter code here
   </html>
```

How `$flipCount` gets number of `$flip`? I don't understand how, could anyone  explain it?

Comment: There is no recursion in the code above…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euh... because of the `$flipCount ++`, which is equivalent to `$flipCount = $flipCount +1` ?

Comment: otherwise what  is "$flipCount ==1" meaning?